# Modifying appsettings in Program doesn't reflect changes in Startup

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to update the `appsettings.json` file of my ASP.NET Core 6 app, *before* my app i fully started. So what I did was this:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == "Local")
        {
            AppSettingsConnectionString.UpdateConnectionString();
        }
    ...
```

Basically, at the very start of my `Main` function, I modify the appsettings file in the `bin\` folder. I have verified that this works.

Then later, in the `Startup.cs` file, specifically in the `ConfigureServices` function, there is a call to `Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")`. However, on that line, I still see the old connection string.

Anyone know how that happens? I updated the file even before I set up the host or the app.

Basically, what I want to do is update the connection string dynamically when the application is run locally.

Comment: The question is unclear. The configuration middleware doesn't edit the configuration sources. There's nothing special about `appsettings.json` either, it's just a JSON settings file whose settings can be overridden by any other source configure after it. Are you trying to treat `appsettings.json` as if it was `app.config` perhaps?

Comment: If you want to use different settings and the built-in `Development` environment isn't enough, you can just add your own settings with `AddJson(path_to_file)`. I use this trick to load different settings files when running on Windows or Linux & Docker. You can get the OS from the Environment class and use it to load different files with OS-specific settings after creating a `HostBuilder`.

Comment: Based on your scenario, you can create a configuration class then you could load your appsettings.json file using `AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);` and finally build our config again.  Point to remember, this approach modifies the configuration in-memory and doesn't persist the changes back to the appsettings.json file.

Comment: you can simply use different configuration files for different environments, like `appsettings.{Environment}.json`

Comment: I know I can use these files and how. But what I'm not understanding is that I modify the file as the very first step of my Program.cs, but don't see it reflected in the behavior of my application.
I have found the issue though, apparently, when debugging, it uses the source file not the one in the bin folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all sorts of debugging and changes in the code, I found the issue.

When debugging, the application will not use the appsettings files in the `bin\` folder, but rather the original source file. So if I want to modify the file, that is the one I will need to modify.